# Add new Line in ScrollingLabel

Tags: roku, brightscript

I tried to successful add XML content in ScrollingLabel. using the below code.

```
<ContentNode>
    <ContentNode title="Nikunj Chaklasiya" />
    <ContentNode title="Computer Science" />
</ContentNode>
```

Here I Both fetch successfully and tried to display newline character after space. For example:
Display

```
Nikunj         Computer
Chaklasiya     Science
```

It is possible. I tried to \n and 
 But It doesn't Work anyone knows that solution.

Comment: Hi @Nikunj, sorry, unable to understand what you are trying to do. Most probably 'ScrollingLabel' is not intended what you are trying to achieve. ScrollingLabel is just to scroll the string if the length of the string is more than the specified width.

Comment: I tried to set more than one line Display in the scrolling label. like the above example scrolling that's fine but Its Display Two line not single one, Is It possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try using Chr(10). I am not sure is this works with XML. You can try within .brs file.

```
scrollabletext = "Nikunj"+ Chr(10) +"Chaklasiya"
```

Which will add new line. If you want two line space then you can use below code:

```
scrollabletext = "Nikunj"+ Chr(10)+ Chr(10) +"Chaklasiya"
```

You can replace space with Chr(10).

Comment: I already tried your answer In Three-component. RowList, Label, and overhang tag. But, nothing happened. I write in XML, brs both files. also tried &#xA; for line breaking.

Comment: Chr(10) works with Label and ScrollableText. Have implemented the same. Please check.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't found. I create a sample Application for testing and create one label. and display label text. you check-in command-line?. command-line work finds. But in Application not work. It's Required any other property set in Label? my Label is `<Label
  id="testLabel"
  height="44"
  width="0"
  font="font:MediumBoldSystemFont"
  horizAlign = "left"
  vertAlign = "center"
  translation="[318,8]" />` my brs file code is `m.scrollabletext = m.top.findNode("testLabel")
    m.scrollabletext.text = "Nikunj"+ Chr(10) +"Chaklasiya"`

Comment: I used the Roku premiere+. I test Chr(10) in All components. But, It's only work in dialog box. Dialog Box documentation is here https://developer.roku.com/docs/references/scenegraph/dialog-nodes/dialog.md